# Django calling a function and coming back to same function

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-views

Currently I have around 5 functions where I use a common code. I was trying to keep this common code as a function and call in these 5 functions.

This will be my common function:

```
def commonfunc(key):
     do something
```

These are kind of my other 5 functions where I use this common code. To change something I have to edit all my 5 functions. I am looking to call this common function in these 5 common functions.

```
def func1(request)
    do something...
    commonfunc(key)
    do something....
    return httpsresponse(request,.....)
```

In this code everything works till second line. Thereafter it does not comeback to func1 and do rest of things.

What I am missing?

Comment: What I am doing is that I send a key to commonfunc and run an api there, result is saved in DB. Then come back to main function and send this data to user. I am not returning any thing to main function. As key is already available in main function and I need to just get this data from DB and send to user.

Comment: I thought mainfunction should get completed and come back automatically after perfoming functions called in it? Please correct if I am wrong.

Comment: Yes, `func1` should resume once `commonfunc` has completed. There is nothing in the pseudo code you have shown that explains why *it does not come back to func1*.

Comment: @Alasdair This is my code. I do not return anything as nothing is required to be returned. commonfunction should call API and save data in database.

Comment: No, that's not your code, it's pseudo code with comments like `do something`. The pseudo code looks ok. Unless you can show actual python code that gives the behaviour you are seeing, it's unlikely we can help.

Comment: My code is right? Should it work the way I want? Or there is something principally wrong?

Comment: Sorry for making it confusing. What I am trying to do is user submit data. I loop through data if it is in my database, if not I call an API, pull data and save in database. Calling API is common code for my 5 functions. I want this calling api (commonfunc) separate to be used in all my 5 functions. So my psuedo code is exact same code I use. Is this code principally correct?

Comment: For the third time: There's nothing wrong with the code you posted.

Comment: Thanks for confirming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can definitely do that. If you want to comeback to func1, you can return something from the commonfunc and accept it in the func1.

```
def commonfunc(key):
    # Do something..
    return something
```

and in the func1..

```
def func1(request)
    # do something...
    s = commonfunc(key)
    # do something....
    return httpsresponse(request,.....)
```

Comment: Though the code in my question was right. But no idea what went wrong. It automatically got fixed. Sometime coding is just magic :)